# Filtered array in PrimeVue datatable?

Tags: vue.js, datatable, primevue

I am new in primevue. I am using the datatable with filtering. I face a problem.

**I want to access the array after the filter applied. But do not find any API to do that.**

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Have you Googled it?

Comment: Yes but do not get the way of getting the filtered array in primevue datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters are stored as an object in your local state. Try using the Vue.js devtools extension to see the format of that object.

Answer (score 2):

I used a slightly different approach (using primevue 2.x).  I added an event handler for the `filter` event.  Then the filtered data is available in the `event.filteredData` property (this is documented in `events` section under the primevue Datatable documentation).

In a nutshell:

- In datatable element in template, add `v-on:filter="onFilter"`
- In code, add following handler:

```js
onFilter: function(event) {
  console.log(event.filteredValue);
},
```

Comment: I think it should be event.filteredValue not event.filteredData

Comment: corrected - thanks cbangor